# Database table that has many-to-many and one-to-many relationship

Tags: mysql, sql, database, relational-database

In the interest of learning more about database design im was drawing up a database model, i choose to draw a simple database model for a social network website to keep a little more interesting than your average student/teacher/class models.

The question i have is about the relationships between the different tables.

Im not that good drawing these text database drawings like other peoples has on stack exchange ill try to just list the tables and explain the relationships, if its unclear i can try to draw a text drawing.

Database tables:

- User
- Friend
- Group
- Newsfeed

User has a one-to-many relationship to Friend and Group based on that one user can have many friends and a user can be a member of several groups and a group can have many users.

Friend has a many-to-many relationship with Group based on that one friend can be a part of many groups and a group can contain many friends. There is a one-to-many relationship to Newsfeed based on that one friend can have many newsfeeds.

Group has a many-to-many relationship with Friend based on that one group can contain many friends and one friend can be part of many groups. Group has a one-to-many relationships with Newsletter based on that one group can have many newsfeeds.

So now there is one many-to-many relationship and a one-to-many relationship in one table point to two other tables, is this correct ? Some part of this feels wrong, especially the Friend part but maybe im just misunderstanding something here. This might be a stupid database model but i need to ask stupid questions sometimes in order to get smarter at something. Ive read about and watch some videos about database relationships and to be they seem easy but when drawing this database model im getting confused since i suddently end up with a many-to-many and a one-to-many relationship in one table which seems weird.

Comment: I dont think you can ask such questions here.

Comment: As long as Data Duplication Data redundancy is not occuring in Tables, I believe you are good to  go. I had a problem in a User Profile Table which has their Address. Some people have the address living in the same state. So, we have to move to a new table by creating as State. Just make sure that Normalization and everything

Answer (score 4):

This is how I'd start:

Let's say we have two groups, Group A and Group B.

```
groups
    id              unsigned int(P)
    name            varchar(30)
    ...

+----+---------+-----+
| id | name    | ... |
+----+---------+-----+
|  1 | Group A | ... |
|  2 | Group B | ... |
| .. | ....... | ... |
+----+---------+-----+
```

Let's say Group A has two newsfeeds and Group B doesn't have any:

```
newsfeeds
    id              unsigned int(P)
    group_id        unsigned int(F groups.id)
    name            varchar(30)
    ...

+----+----------+--------------------+-----+
| id | group_id | name               | ... |
+----+----------+--------------------+-----+
|  1 |        1 | Interesting Things | ... |
|  2 |        1 | Other Information  | ... |
| .. | ........ | .................. | ... |
+----+----------+--------------------+-----+
```

Let's say we have three users: Bob, Mary and John:

```
users
    id              unsigned int(P)
    name            varchar(30)
    ...

+----+------+-----+
| id | name | ... |
+----+------+-----+
|  1 | Bob  | ... |
|  2 | Mary | ... |
|  3 | John | ... |
| .. | .... | ... |
+----+------+-----+
```

A "Friend" is really just another `user` so let's create a table that allows many-to-many relationships between two users. My sample data shows that Bob is friends with Mary and John while Mary is only friends with John. (user_id and friend_id form the Primary Key)

```
users_friends
    user_id     unsigned int \_ (P) (F users.id)
    friend_id   unsigned int /      (F users.id)

+---------+-----------+
| user_id | friend_id |
+---------+-----------+
|       1 |         2 |
|       1 |         3 |
|       2 |         3 |
| ....... | ......... |
+---------+-----------+
```

Users can belong to many groups and each `group` can have many users so we need to have a table that gives us that many-to-many relationship. In my example data we see that Bob is a member of Group A and Group B while Mary and John are only members of Group B. (user_id and group_id form the Primary Key)

```
users_groups
    user_id     unsigned int \_ (P)(F users.id)
    group_id    unsigned int /     (F groups.id)

+---------+----------+
| user_id | group_id |
+---------+----------+
|       1 |        1 |
|       1 |        2 |
|       2 |        2 |
|       3 |        2 |
| ....... | ........ |
+---------+----------+
```

Finally we need a table that shows the relationship between `newsfeeds` and `users`. I haven't entered any example data here but this table works exactly like the `users_groups` table. Tables like this are called many different things, you can read more about them at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table). (user_id and newsfeed_id form the Primary key)

```
users_newsfeeds
    user_id         unsigned int \_ (P) (F users.id)
    newsfeed_id     unsigned int /      (F newsfeeds.id)
```

Comment: thanks for taking the time to write such detailed replies.. but i dont really get it, where is the friend table and i dont see any many-to-many relationships. Dont understand what the Users_Friends table is for when it has a foreign key named FriendID, first i thought that was the Friend table but yea i dont get it.. thanks for trying to explain at least. Writing a completely different database model and not explaining anything doesnt help, but yea like i said appericiate your help

Comment: @user2959896 - well, a Friend is really just another `user`. So the `users_friends` table provides a many-to-many relationship between users. The `users_groups` and `users_newsfeeds` tables are also many-to-many relationships. You don't need a `friend` table because as I mentioned, a friend is really just another `user`.

Comment: @user2959896 - I've edited my answer. Does that help you better? If not, let me know what part isn't making sense to you and I'll see if I can explain my thinking better.

Comment: What is the point of `users_friends`.`id` and `users_groups`.`id` columns? Instead of introducing artificial column here, just go and make PK{user_id, friend_id} (and similar for groups). This the best approach, 'cos without `UNIQUE` constraint you end up having duplicates in the table, despite the presence of the Primary Key, as key is not related to your data.

Comment: @vyegorov - You make an excellent point. The only reason I can think of for having an artificial key like that is to make the table easier to work with using many of the PHP frameworks - and (for me at least) that is not a sufficient reason.

Answer (score 2):

IMO, when thinking about relation modeling, one should remember about the 'direction' of the relation, otherwise it gets very confusing and also, one should remember every 'many to many' relation must have to be modeled using 'one to many'. Anyway, take a look here http://screencast.com/t/sJbPrvO53MS

[image]

even though it took a min to read the question...this was interesting problem...